# Configuring pySpark on Mac to access remote Hadoop Cluster

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark

I need to set up pySpark on my machine to get access and read data on a remote Hadoop cluster, but I'm running into some issues.

These are the step I followed

1) `brew install apache-spark`

2) `export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python:$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH 
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH`

3)

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=yarnconfig
```

In `yarnconfig` I have this in `yarn-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>{Hadoop_Cluster_IP}</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8050</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Here `{Hadoop_Cluster_IP}` is a place holder for the IP address of the Hadoop cluster I'm trying to connect to, which I'm not showing for security reasons.

Then, in a python shell I do

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("LogParser")
```

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

But I get the following error message

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/libexec/python/pyspark/conf.py", line 104, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py", line 245, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/libexec/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 94, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

Do you know what may be going wrong?

Comment: Why do you `.setMaster("local")` ? Are you not trying to connect to a remote cluster?